# + in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to capture a value out of a string. The string's format should be

```
01+XXXX
```

and I want to capture XXXX using a regular expression. This is what I came up with -

```
01+\\s*(?<1>[.0-9]*)
```

But that won't work. What DOES work is -

```
01+\\s*(?<1>[+.0-9]*)
```

The only difference is adding the + into the character class. My main question is - why does the second expression work and the first expression doesn't? In the first one, I look for 01+ and the rest of it should go to [.0-9]. It seems to me that the second one wants to read + twice - is that not what its doing? I am pretty new to regular expressions so I feel like I might be missing something small.

On this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial it says that + is used for "Repeat one or more times". So is it trying to read 01+ more than once?

Comment: My guess would be that the downvoter is perplexed as to why you would learn that `+` is a special character, but still include it in your expression without escaping it.

Comment: Yeah I guess. Didn't realize I had to escape it though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's reading the `1` one or more times. That is, the regex `01+` matches `01` or `011` or `0111` etc.

But it doesn't match the `+`. If you want to match a literal `+`, write `01\+` or `01[+]` for the regex.

Comment: Correct. Escaping the + is enough.

Answer (score 5):

The `+` is a special character, meaning "one or more times." In this case, it means `01`, `011`, `0111`, etc. instead of `01+`. If you want to use it literally, you need to escape it, like this: `\+`

Note: It looks like you are using it with strings, so you would need to double-escape: `\\+`

It works inside a character class (`[+]`) because character classes take most characters literally, with exceptions including `\` and `]`.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the problem, solution and character class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why I can use it literally in [].

Answer (score 3):

'+' is a special character in regex, it means "1 or more times". So what you have written means:

- The character '0'
- The character '1' *one or more times*
- Whitespace 0 or more times
- etc.

If you want to match a literal plus you need to escape it:

```
01\+\\s*(?<1>[.0-9]*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), as explained in the tutorial you linked. So, your regex means "match a zero, then one or more ones, then zero or more whitespaces, then ...".

The plus needs to be escaped:

```
01\\+\\s*(?<1>[.0-9]*)
```

Your second regex worked, because the + there was part of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and does not need to be escaped there.

Answer (score 0):

```
01\+(?<cap>[\d.]*)
```

explain:

```
01                       '01'

\+                       '+'

[\d.]*                   any character of: digits (0-9), '.' 
                         (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```